# Getting undefined method `each` on my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method like this :

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  current_user

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
  ...
end
```

and my route is

```
match 'profile',  :controller => 'profiles', :action => 'index'
```

but when I access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/profile` I get:

> `NoMethodError` in `Profiles#index` undefined method `each` for `nil:NilClass`

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2464854 - i'm using mongoid, just fyi

Comment: This is probably actually occurring in the view. Please look at the entire stack trace to find the relevant view excerpt.

Comment: here we go: https://gist.github.com/2464996 the stacktrace says `Extracted source (around line #36)` which is the following: `<% @users.each do |user| %>`

Comment: Also, I'd hate to be Captain Obvious, but do you actually have any Users in the db?

Comment: lol, yes, i do have Users in my DB. i can only access /profile if logged in

Comment: Seems like User.all is returning nil. Running the code in the rails console or the debugger could maybe give you more info.

Comment: started console with `rails c`, then `users = User.all`. now this `users.size
=> 2
`

Comment: That's strange. Is it possible that some before filter somehow allows the user to get to the Profiles#Index view, but prevents `@users = User.all` from running?

Comment: I don't know...i'm using devise...is it possible that as i'm using `User`as login model, i can only load them via devise?

Comment: No, Devise does not affect your ability to interact with the User mode. Devise only handles interactions at the Controller layer, and makes some view methods available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked. I just removed the line `current_user`from my `ProfilesController` @Jesper do this have something with the filter you said?

Answer (score 2):

This means `User.all` is returning nil. You need to check if there are any users before calling each on them. If you changed your view to look like this it would not raise the error.

```
<% if @users %>          
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I know, but i'm pretty sure I have users on my DB. Look at the comments